# Disable cmake reconfiguring itself from generated build files

Tags: cmake

Let's say you use `cmake` with the `Makefile` generator (the exact generator doesn't really matter here, most do this).

The generated `Makefile` from cmake will build your project, only rebuilding the parts that have changed. As part of this, the `Makefile` also checks if any of the cmake related files have changed (e.g., `CMakeLists.txt`) before running the build and in that case cmake is reconfigured to pick up the changes. So `make` can call `cmake` in this case.

Is it possible to disable this behavior so that the generated make files will not call back into `cmake`?

The context is that if you invoke the original `cmake` command using some kind of wrapper script that sets up a special environment for `cmake`, a later call to `cmake` from `make` won't have this special environment and may do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

> The context is that if you invoke the original cmake command using some kind of wrapper script that sets up a special environment for cmake, a later call to cmake from make won't have this special environment and may do the wrong thing.

This is a bug in your project, not a misfeature of CMake. Anything in your project that is derived from the environment ought to be *cached*. This typically happens automatically when you use built-in `find_*` commands. A pragmatic suggestion: don't read environment variables except to cache them, either directly or via the `HINTS` arguments to `find_*`.

> Is it possible to disable this behavior so that the generated make files will not call back into cmake?

No.